# User Entered Data Displayed once App Restarts

Tags: java, android, user-data

How do I go about displaying user entered data once the app restarts?

Right now, once the app is closed, all the user entered data is erased. Also, after I entered data into activity A, switched to Activity B and then return to Activity A, the data entered in Activity A is also erased.

What is the simplest method to approach this issue?

Comment: For transient data: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState For permanent data: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Data is erased due to that `onDestroy` method is called form your activity when you switch activity

**solution:**

You can use `Shared Preferences` which will save your data even if the app is close
And retrieve data when app is restarted.

you can [click here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) for more info and tutorial about `Shared Preferences`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Shared Preferences` which saves your data even when your app is closed. See [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

To give you more insight in to the implementation, I'm showing you this sample code which should be useful for you to implement:

**for Saving Data:** This You can use during `onStop()`

```
sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("rksData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            file1 = getFilesDir();
            String name1 = username.getText().toString();
            String pwd1 = password.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
            editor.putString("username", name1);
            editor.putString("password", pwd1);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "The data saved by Prefs successfully to ........ : "
                            + file1 + "/rksData", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**for Restoring Data** This you can use during `onCreate()`

```
sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("rksData", 0);
            file3 = getFilesDir();
            String name1 = sharedPrefs.getString("username", " ");
            String pwd1 = sharedPrefs.getString("password", " ");
            username.setText(name1);
            password.setText(pwd1);

            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Data loaded from Prefs Successfully  ........ :" + file3
                            + "/rksData", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need a data storage mechanism. Shared Preferences, the SQLLiteDB or a server/backend like Parse.com would allow you easy data manipulation. Hope this helps.